# Reduce an integer to a single digit by recursively multiplying its digits

Tags: number-theory, recurrence-relations, recursion

Given a positive integer $n_0$, the product of all its digits gives a new number $n_1$, which is smaller than $n_0$.
Repeating this operation eventually reduces the original number to a single digit $n_\infty \in [0, 9]$.

I wrote the following code to perform this operation and tested it on integers in [0, 10 000). The result is plotted below.
Visually I spotted no pattern, and wonders if any pattern exists at all. I posted it here due to my little knowledge of number theory --- also sorry if this is a well-known problem already. Thanks!

Note: one can sum the digits instead of multiplying them, which gives a related question.

```
def productDigits(n):
    prod = 1
    while(n):
        prod *= (n%10)
        n //= 10
    return prod

def convert(n):
    while n > 9:
        n = productDigits(n)
    return n

# print(productDigits(82))
# print(productDigits(39))

# for i in range(11, 100):
#     print(i, ' => ', convert(i))

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(10000)
y = np.array(list(convert(i) for i in x))

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlim(0, 10000)
plt.ylim(0, 10)
plt.show()
```

[image: operation applied to 0 to 10000]

**update**: as was pointed by Gerry Myerson in the comment, this sequence can be found at https://oeis.org/A031347. The single digit that $n$ reduces to is called $n$'s multiplicative digital root, and the number of recursions took is its multiplicative persistence. Similiar concepts exist if sum is used instead of multiplication.

Comment: The width of that plot, sadly, makes it hard to determine anything about what might be happening from it. However, it's safe to say that going to infinity, the moving average will tend to $0$. Among two-digit numbers, $9\%$ have a zero digit; among four-digit numbers, though, that number is $27.1\%$, and it keeps increasing.

Comment: Your function is tabulated at https://oeis.org/A031347 with formulas and references to the literature.

Comment: I think to make the question more interesting you want to omit $0$ and only take the product of the nonzero digits.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks, that's an interesting alternation. When summing the digits we have no such concern, but when multiplying them, the frequent appearance of zero causes a large proportion of the result to be zero.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you for pointing this out! So it's called "Multiplicative Digital Root
". I will modify my question to close it.

Comment: @EricSnyder Thank you. Gerry Myerson pointed out that this sequence is A031347 of oeis. You are correct that it will tends to zero in an average sense.

Comment: Of course this value (multiplicative digital root) is dependent on the base in which $n$ is expressed. You're really looking at the base ten multiplicative digital root.